# Using Oozie to schedule a Hive job that contains a Python UDF

Tags: hive, user-defined-functions, oozie

Is it possible to schedule an Oozie job with a Hive action that itself contains a user defined function written in Python? If so, then how does one supply the Python function to Oozie?

Many thanks